# Using Linq in .net framework 2.0?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, linq

I made an application in .net framework 4.0, visual studio 2010, but due to some reason i changed the framework from 4.0 to 2.0 but now i am getting error that

```
The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you 
missing an assembly reference?)
```

LINQ is very much used in this project, now i want to know that is there any way to use LINQ with .net 2.0.Need help.Thanks.

Comment: Short answer is yes, if you include the DLLs. This question has an answer that explains this to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348348/is-there-a-way-to-use-linq-query-syntax-with-net-3-0-projects

Comment: LINQ was introduced in .NET 3.5

Comment: I guess LINQ was introduced in .NET 3.5,

Answer (score 9):

Linq is not supported in dotnet 2.0

Comment: -1 because there are ways to make it work even on .NET 2.0. See linked answers / questions

Comment: This is a hackish unsupported way

Comment: +1. This answer is right to the point. (Yes, there are workarounds but they are just what they are - _workarounds_)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [LinqBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx), which provides an alternative implementation of the Linq to Objects operators. (note: it works **only** for Linq to Objects, **not** for Linq to XML or Linq to XML...)